# How to maintain cURL HTTP session without storing a cookie?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

This is PHP cURL code I'm using to maintain HTTP session with cookies

```
        if(!function_exists("\curl_init")){
        \load_curl();
        echo "curl loaded";
    } else {
        echo "curl already exists   ";
    }
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');  //could be empty, but cause problems

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $startInterview);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $startInterviewHeaders);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    $startInterviewresponse = curl_exec($ch);
    //echo $response;

    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curl_errno= curl_errno($ch);
    echo "</br> HTTP status: " . $http_status . "</br> cURL error: " .$curl_errno . "</br>";
    //curl_close($ch); //  close cURL
    echo $startInterviewresponse;

    $investigateHeaders = array("SOAPAction: xxx");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $investigateXML);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $investigateHeaders);
    $investigateResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "</br>";
    echo $investigateResponse;

    curl_close($ch);
```

Problem is, system this code should be deployed on does not allow to store cookies and code simply does not work.
So, how can I amend this code to use PHP variables instead of temp file to maintain HTTP session?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `CURLOPT_COOKIE` to set the raw cookie values (presumably ones that are in a variable) and you can check the response headers for the cookies sent by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `php://memory` stream to save session information in memory instead of a filesystem, if you cannot use the filesystem.

Alternatively, you can parse a session id from response `Set-Cookie` header on first request, save it to a variable and send it in a `Cookie` header or by means of `CURLOPT_COOKIE` on every subsequent request.